# WebAudio streaming with fetch : DOMException: Unable to decode audio data

Tags: google-chrome, audio, streaming, fetch, web-audio-api

I'm trying to play an infinite stream coming from the fetch API using Chrome 51. (a webcam audio stream as Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 11025 Hz)

The code works almost OK with mp3s files, except some glitches, but it does not work at all with wav files for some reason i get "DOMException: Unable to decode audio data"

The code is adapted from this answer [Choppy/inaudible playback with chunked audio through Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475982/choppy-inaudible-playback-with-chunked-audio-through-web-audio-api)

Any idea if its possible to make it work with WAV streams ?

```
function play(url) {
  var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var audioStack = [];
  var nextTime = 0;

  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    var reader = response.body.getReader();
    function read() {
      return reader.read().then(({ value, done })=> {
        context.decodeAudioData(value.buffer, function(buffer) {
          audioStack.push(buffer);
          if (audioStack.length) {
              scheduleBuffers();
          }
        }, function(err) {
          console.log("err(decodeAudioData): "+err);
        });
        if (done) {
          console.log('done');
          return;
        }
        read()
      });
    }
    read();
  })

  function scheduleBuffers() {
      while ( audioStack.length) {
          var buffer    = audioStack.shift();
          var source    = context.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.connect(context.destination);
          if (nextTime == 0)
              nextTime = context.currentTime + 0.01;  /// add 50ms latency to work well across systems - tune this if you like
          source.start(nextTime);
          nextTime += source.buffer.duration; // Make the next buffer wait the length of the last buffer before being played
      };
  }
}
```

Just use play('/path/to/mp3') to test the code. (the server needs to have CORS enabled, or be on the same domain your run script from)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the wav stream sound correctly implies to add WAV headers to the chunks as Raymond suggested, plus some webaudio magic and paquet ordering checks;

Some cool guys helped me to setup that module to handle just that and it works beautifully on Chrome : https://github.com/revolunet/webaudio-wav-stream-player

Now works on Firefox 57+ with some config flags on : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader#Browser_compatibility

Comment: supported with some flags on : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I am borrowing your wavify function just to extract a duration of WAV file, but I've got wrong results. If I have a mono, 8Khz wav, I expect to call wavify(buffer, 1, 8000), right?

Answer (score 7):

AudioContext.decodeAudioData just isn't designed to decode partial files; it's intended for "short" (but complete) files.  Due to the chunking design of MP3, it sometimes works on MP3 streams, but wouldn't on WAV files.  You'll need to implement your own decoder in this case.

Comment: Or prepend a WAV header to the each chunk of PCM data before calling `decodeAudioData`.  WAV headers are really simple.

Comment: Thanks Raymond... this sounds a good workaround for me... any idea how to define that header and prepend it to the chunks ?

Comment: experimenting with this idea here : https://gist.github.com/revolunet/46d4187c3b6f28632a91421c1f2a9fad