# Meteor DOMException: Unable to decode audio data

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, meteor

EDIT : I just created a new Meteor Project and it worked :D wow.But it still doesnt work on my core project..looks like i have different settings.

In my Meteor.js project i have 4 `.mp3`-files located in `public/sounds/xyz.mp3`. 
I load these `.mp3` with :

```
 let soundRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    soundRequest.open('GET', this._soundPath, true);
    soundRequest.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    let $this = this;
    soundRequest.onload = function () {
        Core.getAudioContext().decodeAudioData(soundRequest.response, function (buffer) {
            $this.source.buffer = buffer;
            $this.source.loop = true;
            $this.source.connect($this.panner);
        });
    };
soundRequest.send();
```

This WORKS on `google Chrome`, but when i build the app via `meteor run android-device`, i get the following error message : `DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`
I wonder if this is a bug because loading `.png` or `.jpg` works just fine in the mobile version. I have not installed any packages beside `meteor add crosswalk` but deinstalling this doesnt help either.

Comment: can you post complete error or stacktrace here?

Comment: Read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData

Comment: @lolio did you had a chance to look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589614/webaudio-streaming-with-fetch-domexception-unable-to-decode-audio-data Chunking the stream could probably work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This web API is not supported on android device but works on chrome browser of android

Check browser specification in this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to do a http request to get a local resource. You can just refer to a local url. On the Android device the path is different. See this code:

```
  function getSound(file) {
    var sound = "/sounds/"+file;
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      var s;
      if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") {
        sfile = cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/app' + sound;
      }
      else {
        sfile = cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + sound;
      }
      var s = new Media(
        sfile,
        function (success) {
          console.log("Got sound "+file+" ok ("+sfile+")");
          s.play();
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log("Get sound "+file+" ("+sfile+") failed: "+err);
        }
      );
    } else {
      var a = new Audio(sound);
      a.play();
    }
  }
```

On a device it loads the sound file asynchronously and then plays it. In the browser it just loads and plays it synchronously.

Comment: hey Mikkel, thx for your reply, the problem is that decodeAudio's first parameter need to be an arraybuffer ? I dont understand how i get the arraybuffer from there?

Comment: Are you doing more with the sound than just playing it?

Comment: Yes I will use it for spatial audio (web audio API)

Comment: Maybe you can use FileReader to get the file in the correct format, see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: Yep i tried that yesterday, but still the same error. This confuses me since loading .jpg works normal