# How to convert ArrayBuffer to AudioBuffer?

Tags: javascript, buffer, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

I am streaming an arrayBuffer to convert to an audioBuffer in order to be able to listen to it.

I am receiving a stream via a websocket event

```
retrieveAudioStream(){
  this.socket.on('stream', (buffer) => {
    console.log('buffer', buffer)
  })
}
```

the `buffer` is an arrayBuffer and I need it to be an `audioBuffer` in order to be able to listen to it on my application.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData

Comment: According to this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589614/webaudio-streaming-with-fetch-domexception-unable-to-decode-audio-data "AudioContext.decodeAudioData just isn't designed to decode partial files". Due to my stream being arrayBuffer chunks, I am not able to decode it with this method. Any other suggestions?

Comment: There is a very [great example that uses MediaSource](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferWhenNeeded.html) (which works the same for audio streams) and I use it for streaming audio chunkwise from a 206 response, it works very well.

Comment: This might help as well. It's using decodeAudioData to decode the ArrayBuffer in an AudioBuffer and appends the chunks together.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143652/web-audio-api-append-concatenate-different-audiobuffers-and-play-them-as-one-son/14148125

Answer (score 7):

You can use `BaseAudioContext.createBuffer()` method.
It is used to

> create a new, empty `AudioBuffer` object, which can then be populated by data, and played via an `AudioBufferSourceNode`

See MDN for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createBuffer

Comment: `AudioBuffer` objects require `Float32Array`s, which is not what the OP has (`ArrayBuffer`s representing chunks of data). Is there a method to convert `ArrayBuffer`s of data chunks into `AudioBuffer`s?

Comment: I believe you can create any typed array from `ArrayBuffer`. So you must be able to convert `ArrayBuffer` into `Float32Array`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're streaming media rather than downloading the file and then decoding the audio data, `AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource()` will be much better suited for your usecase.

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource